# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'content_length'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm runing Python 3.6.8 and trying to read the size of a text file, but I get the error "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'content_length'".  The get_file_object_size function works when I pass it a file posted in an HTTP multipart/form-data post (using Flask), but when I try to read a text file directly from the file system, I get the error.

setup/db_setup.py:

```
file_path = 'myfile.txt'
# Generates the error
get_file_size_by_file_path(file_path)
```

setup/../utils/files.py:

```
def get_file_object_size(fobj):
    if fobj.content_length:
        return fobj.content_length

    try:
        pos = fobj.tell()
        fobj.seek(0, 2)  #seek to end
        size = fobj.tell()
        fobj.seek(pos)  # back to original position
        return size
    except (AttributeError, IOError):
        pass

    # in-memory file object that doesn't support seeking or tell
    return 0  #assume small enough


def get_file_size_by_file_path(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        return get_file_object_size(file)
```

generates error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup/db_setup.py", line 76, in main
    ins, file_uri='myfile.txt', type=1, file_size=get_file_size_by_file_path(file_path))
  File "setup/../utils/files.py", line 20, in get_file_size_by_file_path
    return get_file_object_size(file)
  File "setup/../utils/files.py", line 2, in get_file_object_size
    if fobj.content_length:
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'content_length'
```

Comment: Do `if hasattr(fobj, 'content_length'):`  Content length is a HTTP response header.  Presumably the flask object is part response, part file in its behaviour.

Comment: `print(fobj.__dict__.keys())` will show you the entire set of attributes in the instance dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using flask, I suspect your "file" comes in as a [`flask.Request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request) object, which does have the property `content_length`.

When you pass it a (open) local file, it's of type `_io.TextIOWrapper`, which as you can see from the exception, *does not* have a `content_length` property/attribute.

If you want to check the size of a local file, you'll need to go about it differently. The `.stat()` method from either the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#pathlib.Path.stat) module can help with that:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('file.txt').stat().st_size
19
```

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat('file.txt').st_size
19
```